# Is there a particle with charge to mass ratio such that the gravitational attraction cancels electrostatic repulsion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

Consider two masses $m$ with electric charge $q$ at a distance $r$.

Magnitude of Gravitational force = $\frac{Gmm}{r^2}$

Magnitude of electrostatic force = $\frac{kqq}{r^2}$

So, If the forces are equal and opposite,

$Gm^2 = k q^2$

So, $\frac{q}{m} = \sqrt{\frac{G}{k}}  $

$\sqrt{\frac{G}{k}} = \sqrt{7.4156 \times 10^{-21}} = 8.611388e−11$

Is there a particle with that charge to mass ratio?

Comment: My intuitive answer is no, but there is the problem of units, what units are you using for G and k?

Comment: Is there a fundamental particle fulfilling this? No. But one can make a non-fundamental particle that satisfies this. Millikan oil drops, for example. Choose your favourite number of charged particles and then add uncharged particles until the ratio satisfies this

Comment: No known elementary particles satisfy this, but external black holes (black holes with the maximal possible amount of charge) do.

Answer (score 4):

Your units are off, and there is no reason to equate the two masses nor the two charges in your equation. Hence, the answer to your question will depend on the external gravitational and electrostatic fields. The Millikan oil drop experiment aims to realize a situation where the two forces cancel each other, as a means to measure the strength of charge.

Comment: Or just put a solid object on the ground. Electrostatic repulsion provides the normal force that equals the gravitational attraction between the object and the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

While it is certainly possible, for a given charge and mass, for the magnitude of the electrostatic and gravitational forces to equal in magnitude, as far as I know there is no basis for there being a general relationship between the equations, other than the inverse square law. That's because the electrostatic force between charged particles is independent of the mass of the particles and the gravitational force between charged particles is independent of the charge on the particles.

Because of this, I believe setting the equations equal to each other leads to an erroneous conclusion that there is some sort of relationship between the ratio of charge to mass and the square root of the ratio of the universal gravitational constant and Coulombs constant. As far as I know, no such relationship exists. But I'm willing to listen.

Hope this helps.